# Prevent destructor from being called manually

Tags: php, oop, destructor

I have this class:

```
class Test
{
    private $test = 'ok';

    public function doTest()
    {
        echo $this->test;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->test = 'not ok';
    }
}
```

and the following test case:

```
$test = new Test;
$test->__destruct(); // I wish this would throw a Fatal Error or something...
$test->doTest(); // prints "not ok"
```

What I want to accomplish is to prevent `__destruct()` from being called manually, so that `doTest()` will never print "not ok".

I tried setting the destructor's visibility to `private`, but that just leads to a Fatal Error on object destruction. An option would be to set a flag `$this->destructed` in the destructor and then throw an Exception in `doTest()` if this flag is true, but it wouldn't be very efficient to check for this flag every time the method is called.

So, a `private` destructor is not possible and a flag `$this->destructed` is ugly. Are there better ways?

Comment: What is the point of this? Why would your code be calling the object's destructor manually? - If that's happening, it seems to me like *that* would be the thing to fix, not this.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish. If its a flag whether or not the class has been destructed, why would you care? PHP garbage collects the object and calls its __destruct() method when the object loses scope

Comment: @Atli I want to make sure, no one tries to call __destruct() deliberately. It would break functionality if the object is still alive after its destructor has been called.

Comment: What are you, some control freak? If someone really wants to call destructor, then it is his/her problem.

Comment: Honestly, I think you're over complicating the situation. Manually calling a destructor makes no sense. It should simply be assumed that destroying an object while it's still in use will cause problems. If somebody does it, then that would be a bug in *that* code. - You can't, and shouldn't, try to make sure nonsense situations like that are impossible.

Comment: It definitely makes sense what you are saying. One should assume that calling `__destruct()` directly will break something. On the other hand, it makes the effort of checking input parameters, throwing exceptions and setting _unsafe_ properties and methods to `private` or `protected` feel somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the destructor to be called, don't implement it. Instead, use a `private` delegate to do the shutdown stuff.

Your class:

```
class Test
{
    private $delegate;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->delegate = new TestDelegate;
    }

    public function doTest()
    {
        echo $this->delegate->test."\n";
    }
}
```

Delegate:

```
class TestDelegate
{
    public $test = 'ok';

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->test = 'not ok';
        echo __METHOD__." called\n";
    }
}
```

Test:

```
$test = new Test;
//$test->__destruct(); // fatal error
$test->doTest(); // prints "ok"
// TestDelegate::__destruct() gets called automatically
```

---

Now, this may introduce other problems. How to make sure the delegate gets registered if a child class implements a constructor and forgets to call its parent constructor? And wouldn't it break things if the constructor gets called multiple times?

To deal with that, make the constructor `final` and `private` and use a factory method:

```
public static function create()
{
    return new static;
}
```