# PHP garbage collector: assume specific order of destruction

Tags: php, garbage-collection, destructor

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20836467/2032498) to the question ['Prevent destructor from being called manually'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20808882/2032498) I was wondering if it might be dangerous to rely on the garbage collector to destruct the object `private $delegate` in the intended order.

The [PHP Manual regarding Destructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) says:

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

Ok. So if the object somehow survives until the shutdown sequence, **there will be a problem**.

Let's assume we make sure the object does not survive until the shutdown sequence and therefore gets destructed "as soon as there are no other references" to it. At the moment that means, as soon as the instance of `Test` gets destructed, its property `$delegate` will also be destructed subsequently.

But what if in future PHP versions the garbage collector gets smarter and somehow "detects" that the instance of `Test` does not make use of its property `$delegate` and destructs it while `Test` is still alive? That would be unfortunate.

Question in short: Is the last paragraph a conceivable scenario or will an object 'A' registered as a property of an object 'B' always get destructed *after* 'B' is destructed (assuming we're not in the shutdown sequence)?

Comment: So your question is based on a 'hypothetical` future situation that assumes `smarter` means `more stupid`?

Comment: `no other references` would seem to imply rather clearly that the intention is that it won't change. If the wording were `no other _active_ references` or any other "can be read with another meaning in the future" words involved, I'd be more careful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on speculative fiction

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I suspected as much. Is there a StackExchange site that's more suitable for this kind of question?

Comment: I guess [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) would have been a better site for this question. My fault.

Comment: After reviewing the [guidelines for on-topic questions on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this question would be invalid on that site as well. What I need is a community of time travellers ;-)

Comment: @MarkBaker in reply to your first comment: I asked this question because _abusing_ the GC as "private destructor" seems a bit risky and feels like outsmarting the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to believe that PHP will ever have a  garbage collector instead of the current reference counting mechanism.

Even if there was, as long as the live object holds a pointer to the "delegate" object no garbage collector can delete the delegate object, so don't worry, you're safe.